# In CrafterCMS, how do I configure Solr in Crafter 3.0?

Tags: java, solr, content-management-system, crafter-cms

I'm installing a production `Crafter 3.0` instance built from source, using the current documentation as guidance. However, I'm having issues at this point:

```
 Change the path where the preview Solr search indexes will be stored, e.g. /opt/crafter/data/preview-indexes:

 In INSTALL_DIR/apache-tomcat/solr-crafter/conf/solrconfig.xml, update the value of <dataDir> to the preview indexes folder path (e.g. <dataDir>/opt/crafter/data/preview-indexes</dataDir>).
```

I can't find the `INSTALL_DIR/apache-tomcat/solr-crafter/conf/solrconfig.xml` file, and `solr` itself seems to be in different path.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since 3.0 Solr is now it's own standalone service.

It's highly recommended to use this [as a template to start up a production](https://github.com/craftercms/craftercms#2-build-a-deployable-bundle) install (you might want to tweak memory, paths,backups and Apache frontend for all the services).

Now if for some reason you have a special Solr config all solr config will be under `crafter-(auth|delivery)-env/solr/server/solr/configsets/crafter_configs`

Here more on Solr 6.x configuration https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Config+Sets and/or
https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Configuring+solrconfig.xml